# How to find performance hot spots in .Net application?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, performance

I have an existing ASP.NET 2.0 web service serves several WinForms clients. In our application, We belive we have performance problem in several levels.

1. Sending toomuch data in syncrounous
   request
2. Lazy loading, Too many round trip
   between web service and database
3. POCO <-> Sql object mapping using
   untyped datasets and reflection[no
   caching]

This is an existing application with large code base, I would like to instrument this app to find out hotspots.

1. How can I instrument remote apps
   like winforms client deployed in
   remote places?
2. How can I instrument Web Service?
3. **Edit**** Are there any profilers better than VS profiler?
4. Can I trust the profilers to tell me the
   hot spots, so I don't pollute my code
   with instrumentation? Or Do I have
   to take the middle road, profiler +
   instrumentation?

Comment: posted similare question today some hours ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785917/asp-net-measure-performance/5785966#5785966

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may help:
[ASP.NET and WorkerThreads – Interesting performance tweaks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sujitdmello/archive/2007/11/10/asp-net-and-workerthreads-interesting-performance-tweaks.aspx)
[20 Tips to Improve ASP.net Application Performance](http://www.realsoftwaredevelopment.com/20-tips-to-improve-aspnet-application-performance)
[Use Custom Http Handlers To Improve Performance in ASP.NET](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20030113.asp)
[Best practices for ASP.Net applications](http://www.abstraction.net/content/articles/best%20practices%20for%20asp.net%20applications.htm)
[Scaling Strategies for ASP.NET Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500561.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking out [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/). I confess I haven't used this, but I've used their other flagship product (Resharper) which is outstanding.

Comment: I've had good results with dotTrace for performance profiling/optimization, though I believe you'll need to have this deployed on the client machine if you want to profile a remote client (I've only ever used it for local machine profiling.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a great tool for profiling and troubleshooting a live web app: http://newrelic.com/